# Template function to convert std::string in std::wstring and vice_versa with compile time checking

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I have the following functions:

```
std::string convert(const std::wstring &str);
std::wstring convert(const std::string &str);
```

Which I would like to do something like this:

```
template<class T, class U> T convert(const U& u);
```

I created some verification:

```
template<class T> struct is_string : public std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_string<std::basic_string<T>> : public std::true_type {};
```

And then now I'm confusing on how to do that in a really strict way: if `T` is `std::string`, `U` must be a `std::wstring` and vice-versa. All other cases shouldn't compile.

Any clue?

**My compiler is on C++11**

Thanks.

Comment: `static_assert` the `T` and `U`?

Comment: Or maybe `std::enable_if` on `(std::is_same_v(T, std::string)::value && std::is_same_v(U, std::wstring)::value) || (std::is_same_v(T, std::wstring)::value && std::is_same_v(U, std::string)::value)`?

Comment: However, since there are only 2 possible combinations, a single template really doesn't make much sense in the first place. I would suggest you just keep using the 2 separate overloads instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not particularly elegant... but I suppose you can write something as follows

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>


template <typename T, 
          typename U = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, std::string>::value,
                                                 std::wstring,
                                                 std::string>::type>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::string>::value
                     || std::is_same<T, std::wstring>::value, U>::type
    convert (T const & s)
 { /* do something */ return {}; }

int main ()
 {
   auto ws = convert(std::string{});
   auto s = convert(std::wstring{});

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(ws), std::wstring>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(s), std::string>::value, "!" );
 }
```

or (maybe better) with a custom type traits

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template <typename>
struct swapString
 { };

template <>
struct swapString<std::string>
 { using type = std::wstring; };

template <>
struct swapString<std::wstring>
 { using type = std::string; };

template <typename T, 
          typename U = typename swapString<T>::type>
U convert (T const & s)
 { /* do something with s */ return {}; }

int main ()
 {
   auto ws = convert(std::string{});
   auto s = convert(std::wstring{});

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(ws), std::wstring>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(s), std::string>::value, "!" );
 }
```

But are you sure you want a single function and not 2 overloaded functions?